# Levelized in" levelized cost of energy"

Tags: meaning, terminology, technical

I have read a report titled "Lazard's Levelized Cost of Energy Analysis.

What does this technical term "levelized cost of energy" mean?

Comment: If I understand your first sentence correctly, you not only "saw the title" but actually read this report. So how did the report itself define the word?

Comment: Hi. In this report is assumed that you know what it means. namely it seems this(levelized cost of energy) is a technical Expression.(maybe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia article on [Cost of Electricity by Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_of_electricity_by_source#Levelized_Cost_of_Energy),

> **Levelized Energy Cost**  is the price at which electricity must be generated from a specific source to break even over the lifetime of the project. It is an economic assessment of the cost of the energy-generating system including all the costs over its lifetime: initial investment, operations and maintenance, cost of fuel, and cost of capital.

Comment: yes. you are right jeff

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't find it in many if any dictionaries, but I'd have thought the meaning is pretty obvious *(to levelise/levelize = **to make level**)*. Also note this from the full OED...

> **levelization**, noun.
>    *‘The act of levelling or reducing to equality’.*
>
> First recorded 1860 *Gentleman's Magazine*. cited in Worcester.

---

In context it's actually a slightly specialised meaning. It's not about making all *current* energy prices "equal" - more a matter of [amortising](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amortize) all costs (startup, decommissioning, etc.) for each specific form of power generation (so the cost for any given method is "constant, level" over time).

Comment: There is also a verb *to level*, and we talk about *levelling the ground prior to building* etc. As long as we don't start *levellizing* the playing field I shall not object.

Comment: @WS2: I suspect they came up with this particular "jargon" because they thought ***amortizing*** only applied to ***future** payment of **current** costs*. (I spelt it the American way there, since I'm sure this is primarily an AmE usage! :)

Comment: I'm not sure the OP is talking about *amortization* or what. It could be a statistical levelling to eliminate seasonal variations or any one of a hundred other things.

Comment: @WS2: It's [all in here](http://www.iser.uaa.alaska.edu/people/berman/personal/Econ394b/Levelized_cost.html), but I'm not really bothered about the precise meaning. That's domain-specific, to say the least.